# Find a combination of k numbers in a given sequence of numbers satisfying the condition

Tags: algorithm, combinations

I have a problem like this:

> Given a list of numbers with n `(10 <= n <= 60)` numbers `x1, x2,..., xn`
> such that `1 <= xj <= 10`. Enter the number k `(1 <= k <= 8)`, enter the
> number m `(0 <= m <= 9)`. Find a combination of k numbers in the given
> list of numbers such that the sum of the k numbers found modulo 10
> equals m. For example: for the sequence `N = {1,3,5,6,3,7,2,9,10,3,4,6}`
> with k = 3 and m = 5, then one of the satisfying combinations is `{5,6.4} -> (5 + 6 + 4) % 10 = 5`.

I want to find the optimal solution to the problem but i haven't found a way other than using recursion to brute-force. Is there a better way than brute-force?
Thank you for your reading!

Comment: The technique at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71377498/find-all-possible-combinations-of-n-numbers-in-an-array-which-sums-to-a-given-va/71387075#71387075 works.  Just replace "sum" with "sum mod 10" and take the first solution it gives.  (It will let you efficiently find all of them, which is a bit of overkill for your problem.)

Comment: Recursion sounds good.

Comment: If you show us yours, we can probably make it much faster easily.

Comment: @btilly `Just replace "sum" with "sum mod 10"...` do you mean try each case: m, m + 10, m + 20,...?

Comment: No. I mean that `indexes_by_sum_by_count` should be `indexes_by_sum_mod10_by_count` along with the necessary changes to make the name accurate.